# Passing keys of object to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive as a wrapper for `md-autocomplete` so that it's easier to re-use. In the parent controller, I have an object. I want to pass the keys of the object to my custom directive, but I'm having trouble. Simplified code, without `md-autocomplete`:

Here's the script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('parentController', function(){
  var parent = this;
  parent.things = {item1: {color: "blue"}, item2: {color: "red"}};
})
.directive('childDirective',function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
       items:'&'
    },
    controller: childController,
    controllerAs: 'child',
    template: '<pre>{{child.items | JSON}}<pre>' //should be [item1,item1]
  }

  function childController(){
    //Just a dummy controller for now
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentController as parent">
    <my-directive items="Object.keys(parent.things)">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

**TL;DR:** How do I pass the keys of an object defined in the parent controller to a child directive? I need to pass just the keys, not the object itself, because my directive is designed to deal with an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a directive with local scope from user attribute (=)

```
app.directive('childDirective', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
         items: '='
    },
    template: '<pre>{{items | JSON}}<pre>'
  };
});
```

Using the directive, object in attribute "items" is passed "as is" , as a scope variable "items"

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="parentController as parent">
    <my-directive items="getKeys(parent.things)">
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Using Object.keys(obj) as source will cause an infinite loop digest (the function is always returning a new different object). You need a function to save the result to a local updatable object, like in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/FranIg/3ut4h5qm/3/

```
$scope.getKeys=function(obj){
  //initialize result
  this.result?this.result.length=0:this.result=[];
  //fill result
  var result=this.result;  
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item){
   result.push(item);
   })
  return result;
}
```

Comment: So you're saying I have to re-design my directive to process an object rather than an array? There is no reasonable way to get the keys of an object in the parent scope and pass them to the directive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking @Igor's answer as correct, because ultimately it led me to the right place. However, I wanted to provide my final solution, which is too big for a comment.

The search for the answer to this question led me to create a directive that is more flexible, and can take several different types of input.

The real key (and my actual answer to the original question) was to bind the `items` parameter to a proxy getter/setter object in the directive. The basic setup is:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
  return {
    ...
      controller: localControl,
      bindToController: {
        items: '<' //note one-way binding
      }
    ...
  }
  function localControl(){
    var child = this;
    child._items = [],

    Object.defineProperties(child,{
       items: {
         get: function(){return child._items},
         set: function(x){child._items = Object.keys(x)}
       }
    });
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<my-directive items="parent.items">
  <!-- where parent.items is {item1:{}, item2:{}...} -->
</my-directive>
```

Ultimately, I decided I wanted my directive to be able to accept a variety of formats, and came up with [this plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/2v9aougYdfdHfZkCS7pz/) as a demonstration.

Please feel free to offer comments/suggestions on improving my code. Thanks!